# receive a large amount of data from Azure Storage and process it

Tags: c#, .net, list, azure, azure-storage

I need to migrate some data from Azure Storage to Sql db.

I have the following code :

```
class AzureDataAccessManager : IAzureDataAccessManager
{
    private readonly CloudTable tableClient;

    private readonly CloudStorageAccount storageAccount;

    public string TableName { get; }

    public AzureDataAccessManager(string connectionString, string tableName)
    {
        TableName = tableName ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(tableName));

        if (connectionString == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(connectionString));

        storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);

        tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient().GetTableReference(TableName);
    }

    public List<T> QueryAllRecords<T>() where T : class, ITableEntity, new()
    {
        TableContinuationToken token = null;

        var entities = new List<T>();
        do
        {
            var queryResult = tableClient.ExecuteQuerySegmented(new TableQuery<T>(), token);
            entities.AddRange(queryResult.Results);
            token = queryResult.ContinuationToken;

        } while (token != null);

        return entities;
    }
}
```

And I am getting all the records like this :

```
var result = azureTableManager.QueryAllRecords<AzureCpaDataEntity>();
```

The problem is I don't know, how many rows I'll have there. What if it will be too large? Maybe get via some ranges (10 thousands or whatever), but as I see there is no respective method in List.

Help me with some solutions or ideas, please!

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of returning all entities from `QueryAllRecords` method, you should actually return query result which will have a maximum of 1000 entities and the continuation token. Process that data, and then call this method again for next set of entities by passing the continuation token.

Comment: The very query you used return paged results. That's why it's called "ExecuteQuery*Segmented*". Paging is the default, often the *only* option with cloud providers precisely because they deal with large numbers of objects. 10K is too little, a container could contain millions of objects.

Comment: If you check [the method's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.cloudtable.executequerysegmented?view=azure-dotnet) you'll see all overloads accept a continuation token. The result class itself, [TableQuerySegment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.tablequerysegment-1?view=azure-dotnet), has a `ContinuationToken` property whose value should be used to get the *next* batch of results

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks, will have a try!

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos what if List will be overloaded? How should I handle it?

Comment: @rfedytc don't use the List. You already use the token, process the results in batches as they arrive. Instead of returning a List, turn your method into an iterator method and return the batches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question's code already retrieves results in batches. Instead of waiting for *all* of them to arrive, the method could be turned into an iterator and return each batch immediatelly :

```
public IEnumerable<List<T>> QueryRecords<T>() where T : class, ITableEntity, new()
{
    TableContinuationToken token = null;

    do
    {
        var queryResult = tableClient.ExecuteQuerySegmented(new TableQuery<T>(), token);
        token = queryResult.ContinuationToken;
        yield return queryResult.Results;

    } while (token != null);
}
```

The results should be processed in batches as well :

```
foreach(var batch in QueryRecords<AzureCpaDataEntity>())
{
    ProcessTheBatch(batch);
}
```